# "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties" in identical code

Tags: c#

I have two nearly identical blocks of code in two separate projects; the second project was created to use the same ConnectClass as the first.

However, in the new project (the second code block shown below), the compiler gives the following error message regarding the error handler static void client_ErrorEvents(object sender, a.b.c.ErrorEventArgs e):

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ProjectName.ConnectClass.client_ErrorEvents(object, a.b.c.ErrorEventArgs)' and 'ProjectName.ConnectClass.client_ErrorEvents(object, a.b.c.ErrorEventArgs)'

HERE IS THE FIRST CODE BLOCK (IN RELEVANT PART)

```
public partial class ConnectClass
{

    public static a.b.c.Client client = new a.b.c.Client();
    public static string DriveLetter;
    public static string CurrentDate;

    //_____________________

    public static void StoreVars(Form1 frm)
    {
        DriveLetter = frm.textBox4.Text;
        CurrentDate = frm.textBox5.Text;
    }

    public static string Connect(Form1 frm, int Call)
    {
        string host = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 7496;
        int clientId = 0;

        string Result = "Connected";

        try
        {
            client.Connect(host, port, clientId);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Result = e.ToString();
        }

        //if (Call == 0)
        client.Error += new EventHandler<a.b.c.ErrorEventArgs>(client_ErrorEvents);

        return Result;
    }

    static void client_ErrorEvents(object sender, a.b.c.ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        int ErrorCode;

        string path = DriveLetter + "/ThisPath/File.txt";
        FileStream ThisFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ThisFile);

        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        ErrorCode = (int)e.ErrorCode;
        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        sw.Write(dtNow);
        sw.Write(" ");
        sw.Write(e.ErrorCode);
        sw.Write(" ");
        sw.Write(e.ErrorMsg);
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        sw.Close();
        ThisFile.Close();
    }
```

---

HERE IS SECOND CODE BLOCK (IN RELEVANT PART)

```
public partial class ConnectClass
{
    public static a.b.c.Client client = new a.b.c.Client();
    public static string DriveLetter;
    public static string CurrentDate;

    //_____________________

    public static void StoreVars(Form1 frm)
    {
        DriveLetter = frm.TBx_Drive.Text;
        CurrentDate = frm.TBx_Date.Text;
    }

    public static string Connect(Form1 frm)
    {
        string host = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 7496;
        int clientId = 10;

        string Result = "Connected";

        try
        {
            client.Connect(host, port, clientId);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Result = e.ToString();
        }

        client.Error += new EventHandler<a.b.c.ErrorEventArgs>(client_ErrorEvents);

        return Result;
    }
```

// THIS IS WHERE THE COMPILER SIGNALS AN ERROR:

```
    static void client_ErrorEvents(object sender, a.b.c.ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = DriveLetter + "/ThisPath/File.txt";
        FileStream ThisFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ThisFile);

        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        ErrorCode = (int)e.ErrorCode;
        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        sw.Write(dtNow);
        sw.Write(" ");
        sw.Write(e.ErrorCode);
        sw.Write(" ");
        sw.Write(e.ErrorMsg);
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        sw.Close();
        ThisFile.Close();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

You have single class split between 2 files (`partial`) and both implement the same function.

Either make them non-partial (you'll probably have name conflict on classes), or don't have duplicate methods in the same class.

See details about using `partial` in [Partial Classes and Methods in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: There probably won't be a name conflict if they are different projects.

Comment: @BartoszKP somehow both parts are visible in "new project" so just removing `partial` from one or both will still keep both classes visible... I'd expect name conflict.

Comment: Alexei is correct.  In the second project, there was already an event handler by the same name in a separate file of the same partial class containing event handlers.  The second file contained a large number of event handlers written by a different programmer and I didn't know that handler was there.  Thanks for pointing that out, Alexei.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If there is a `using` directive for both assemblies than yes, there will be a "conflict", but not in the sense of an unusable code. With explicit assembly/namespace qualification there would be no conflict and both classes can be used. Good answer anyway :)